# Prove that the direction in Least Angle Regression makes equal angle with all predictors

Tags: regression, machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, least-squares, regularization

Least Angle Regression iteralively adds predictors according to the procedure described here : [Writing by hand first steps in Least Angle Regression (LARS)](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/404984)

We note $A_{k}$ the active set of variables at the beginning of step k, $X_{A_{k}}$ the vector of the predictors at step k, and $u_{k}$ the direction of least angle regression at step k.

Show that all variables in $X_{A_{k}}$ make equal angle with the direction $u_{k}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fit direction at step $k$ is $u_{k}=X_{A_{k}}\delta_{k}$ where $\delta_{k}=(X^{T}_{A_{k}}X_{A_{k}})^{-1}X^{T}_{A_{k}}r_{k}$. Thus we have $X_{A_{k}}^{T}u_{k}=X_{A_{k}}^{T}X_{A_{k}}\delta_{k}=X_{A_{k}}^{T}X_{A_{k}}(X^{T}_{A_{k}}X_{A_{k}})^{-1}X^{T}_{A_{k}}r_{k}=X_{A_{k}}^{T}r_{k}$.

From the definition of cosine between two vectors $u$ and $x_{j}$, $cos(u,x_{j})=\frac{x_{j}^{T}u}{\|x_{j}\|\|u\|}=\frac{x_{j}^{T}u}{\|u\|}$, so that each element of $X_{A_{k}}^{T}u_{k}$ is the cosine beetween a selected predictor at step k and the direction $u_{k}$.

The LAR procedure adds vector $x_{l}$ precisely when $|x_{l}^{T}r|=|x_{j}^{T}r|$ for each predictor $x_{j}$ in $A_{k}$ hence $u_{k}$ makes same angle with all predictors in $A_{k}$.